# How to use GDB when two programs have to interact?

Tags: linux, gdb

This case may be a bit complex , and I don't know if there are easy solutions for it .

I have a program A , for which I'm trying to exploit a heap buffer overflow vulnerability , and that means , I have to input special characters beyond the range of standard ascii to set up parts of the memory addresses. This is done through stdin , but the program is interactive , so it means that there are multiple steps before inputting data like buffers , shellcodes etc. Imagine program A doing something like :

1. ask for a name : you enter the name.
2. presents 5 choices (adding a name , deleting a name , exiting the program etc) , and you input the number of the choice you want : you enter the number (for example 1 for adding a user)
3. Demands the size of the name of the user you want to allocate : you enter the size.
4. Demands to input the string of the buffer .

Now , since I've found the vulnerability (a 2 byte overflow) , I need to be able to input special characters in this place , so , since doing it by hand would be extremely tiresome , I've attached programA to netcat by doing `nc -lnp 7777 -e programA` , and wrote programB with some sockets to be able to communicate with programB and being able to send whatever bytes I want.

The problem is that I need to be able to use GDB , with the inputs of programB , to keep track of registers values and the content of memory.

So , to sum up the problem here , GDB has to behave like a server and host programA , and react to the inputs of programB through netcat or socat.

PS : programA is only compiled code binary , I have no idea what code is in there , except assembly , and I can't change it.

EDIT : I just discovered a nice library in python called pwntools that does pretty much what I want , if anyone has an equivalent C library , feel free to share

Comment: Do you know that GDB's `run` command can take input/output redirects? e.g. `run < payload`, you can also make GDB use a different TTY for I/O (possibly using a PTY). See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.htm

Comment: @Hasturkun yes  but doing that cause the program to loop indefinitely ...
doing ```echo 'stuff' | ./program``` also has the same effect .
your link is broken by the way

Comment: Although how to work with gdb is definitely on topic here, requests for third-party tool recommendations are explicitly *off* topic.